# Orthogonal Camera Clip/Hide part of 3D model

Tags: camera, godot, clipping

How to prevent the `Camera` from `Clipping/Hiding` part of the 3D Model/Object?

I tried playing around with `Near`/`Far` properties , but it doesn't change the result.

EDIT: it happens when the `Camera` follow the player : https://youtu.be/ewi-TzI3204

I'm moving the `CameraRig` which the `Camera` is child of it:

```
void MainCamera::_process(float delta)
{
    auto pos = hero->get_translation();
    pos.y = 0;
    camera_rig->set_translation(pos);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried moving the camera further away from the scene?

Comment: I tried moving it, but when the `camera` follow the player , that happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, silly me , I didn't see the `Camera` port of view is going through the floor, which was the reason it was clipping:

[image]

moving the `Camera` up , fixed the issue :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Move the `Camera` away.

*I'm not suggesting to move the `CameraRig`, as the `CameraRig` is moved by code. Instead change the (local) transform of the `Camera`. Which is relative to its its parent (i.e. the `CameraRig`).*

Even though the `Camera` is using an orthogonal projection. It still has a position in the world, and things behind the `Camera` get clipped. *Remember that the near plane is always in front of the `Camera`.*

Thus, pull the `Camera` away. Position it distant enough that everything that should be visible is visible.

That, of course, is no way around objects getting close to the `Camera` anyway. You can try setting objects materials with "Distance Fade" to handle that.

Comment: pulling the camera away, and moving it around will work at the beginning , but once the player move and the camera follows , this clipping happens

Comment: @Abanoub Are you moving the `Camera` or are you moving the `CameraRig`? Have the `CameraRig` follow the player, and then the `Camera` being a child of the `CameraRig` can have a transform relative to it.

Comment: I'm doing exactly that , I have updated the question

Comment: @Abanoub I have to reiterate, move the `Camera`. I can see both in the image in the question and the linked video that the `Camera` has a transform of 4 on the y and 5 on the z... That is not changing as the player moves around. If you change that transform, it will not be undone when the player moves. Move the `Camera` further away.